# Tramp file encoding for Unix

Tags: tramp, newlines

I have managed to setup Tramp to connect to a remote Solaris machine from a Windows machine using plink, which is very nice.

```
 (setq tramp-default-user "Beginner"
       tramp-default-host "the_host"
       tramp-default-method "plink")
```

But now I have a host of new problems, which I would assume to be related to the file encoding from the tramp upload:

For example I have edited the .profile and now I get strange error messages like

```
$>. .profile
bash: $'\r': command not found
```

How can I configure tramp to format files in a Solaris-friendly way?

---

Edit: Having unix-encoding the default solves the issue for me

```
 (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, Tramp shall respect encoding of existing files. For new files, you could set the encoding via `C-x RET f utf-8-unix RET`. You can choose also another coding system, the important point is to append the `-unix`suffix. Read also the Emacs manual about coding systems.